# Adding Personal Google API into Fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I want to have my google api added to fancybox once my googlemaps img is click on.

[heres the url](http://www.rhythmdesignz.biz/)

I would like that once the google img is clicked it opens a lightbox from fancybox and then runs the google api in light box.

I know I can just add a iframe and use fancybox to enter it in, but since Im learning javascript at the moment I would like to see how this would work.

[I have found the js code that is ran from fancybox here](http://rhythmdesignz.biz/code/fancy-box/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js)

The html from lightbox is

```
<div class="fancybox-outer">
<div style="overflow: visible; width: 350px; height: 280px;" class="fancybox-inner">

<img class="fancybox-image" src="images/directv_g_map.jpg" alt="">

</div>
</div>
```

I would not have posted this if I could have done this myself but after 10+ hours trying to do this Ive gotten frustrated that I cant clearly think.

> -Ive been attempting to have the google api do an window onclick = init; then run ----didnt work
>   -different versions of onclick and onload ---- didnt work
>   -The one I believed would have worked best would be the createElement, but I have been having trouble getting the id for the lightbox img since it only has the class tag.
>   I planned on editing the js file just to include a if statement which would the create a div id where I can then load my google api but yet no luck.
>   -if(src == "directv_g_map.jpg") then change src to google api

again I still learning but would appreciate some help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use 'afterShow' event which is fired after fancybox content shown.

Then you can replace your image inside fancybox by a div and initialize google map.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    width   :   '70%',
    height  :   '70%',
    afterShow: function InitMap(){
            //replace image with div 
            $('.fancybox-image').replaceWith("<div id='map' style='width: 100%;height: 100%;'></div>");
            //set up and initialize map
            var mapOptions = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.784887,-106.356604),
                    zoom: 15,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);    

        }
});
```

here's [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/paulitto/gSedw/2/)

you can find more about fancybox events/methods [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) (this link is on top of your fancybox js file)

Comment: Thank You Paulitto!<br/> I was working on it now for another hour and finally have everything perfect. I dont know how exactly the voting systme here works but I clicked the check mark. Hope it helps you to.